# Multiple file upload(stripes)

Tags: file-upload, stripes

I am trying to make a file upload that will accept multiple files using the stripes framework. I have a single file upload working. I am trying to understand the [Documentation](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/File+Uploads) for multiple file upload.

According to the doc, all I need to do is modify single file example to:

```
<stripes:form>
    <c:forEach ... varStatus="loop">
        ...
        <stripes:file name="newAttachments[${loop.index}]"/>
        ...
    </stripes:form>
```

ActionBean

```
private List<FileBean> newAttachments;

public List<FileBean> getNewAttachments() {
    return this.newAttachments;
}

public void setNewAttachment(List<FileBean> newAttachments) {
    this.newAttachments = newAttachments;
}
```

What do I need to replace the `...`(in particular, the one in the forEach loop) with to get this example working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that should work:
`<c:forEach begin="1" end="3" varStatus="loop">`

see [Tag forEach doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html)