# Uploading multiple files with stripes

Tags: jsp, stripes

I am trying to upload multiple files and bind them to a java array in the stripes framework. I have read the documentation [here](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/File+Uploads) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995065/multiple-file-uploadstripes) on SO. However, I am still having issues. While running in debug, if I upload multiple files I notice that only the last file is bound to the array. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<stripes:form>
<c:forEach varStatus="loop" begin="0" end="3">
<stripes:file name="attachments[${loop.index}]"/>
</c:forEach>
<stripes:submit name="submit" />  
</stripes:form>

private List<FileBean> attachments = new ArrayList<FileBean>();
public void setAttachments(List<FileBean> attachments) throws IOException {
    logger.info("*********************Attachments " + attachments.size());
    this.attachments = attachments;
    //documentation says to call FileBean.save or read them as a stream

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave out the setter. The `attachments` variable is already initialized via the `new` operator.

```
private List<FileBean> attachments = new ArrayList<FileBean>();

public List<FileBean> getAttachments() {
    return this.attachments;
}

public Resolution submit() {
    System.out.println("********************* Attachments " + attachments.size());
    return show();
}

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution show() {
    return new ForwardResolution("[path to jsp]");
}
```

Pressing 'submit' on the form calls the 'submit' Resolution where you can now inspect the populated attachments, save them, and - in this example - return to the form again. Or you could show your visitors another page.

Comment: I tried that, but when I upload two files in other words control clicking on two files in the file dialog box. The array only holds one item in debug mode. I need to be able to populate the attachments array with n attachments

Comment: You mean a `<input type='file' multiple ... />`? I wouldn't say it's impossible in Stripes but it probably is not easy. There's bean a discussion on the mailing list last year https://sourceforge.net/p/stripes/mailman/message/34787765/ Maybe try an ajax (jQuery) script, as is suggested.